# how to print items of two lists in a same line in python. can't use any pre-defined functions except basic ones

Tags: python, loops

```py
players_list = [a,b,c,d,e]
scores_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want the output to be like:

```
"-a_____________1-"

"-b_____________2-"

"-c_____________3_"
```

and so on

I have tried using a nested loop, 2 loops and text formatting and lots of stuff but still can't figure out.

Comment: `for pair in zip(players_list, scores_list)`

Comment: if you have tried lots of stuff why haven't you posted any code at all?

Comment: At least provide code that works.
`players_list = ["a", "b", "c" ,"d", "e"]`

Comment: sorry in a hurry I gotta submit my assignment in an hour thought my failed code wouldn't be useful ;-;

Answer (score 1):

```
players_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
scores_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for p, s in zip(players_list, scores_list):
    print(f"-{p}_____________{s}-")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#zip) function to combine multiple lists:

```py
players_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
scores_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for player, score in zip(players_list, scores_list):
  print(f'-{player}_____________{score}-')
```

will print

```
-a_____________1-
-b_____________2-
-c_____________3-
-d_____________4-
-e_____________5-
```

Note that I added quotes around the characters in the `players_list` to make them strings and I used [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) for formatting the output.

Alternatively, the print could be

```py
print('-', player, '_____________', score, '-', sep='')
```

if you don't want to use f-strings.